# Swiper events are not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, swiper.js, jquery-isotope

I'm working on a gallery website which uses the Swiper 
JQuery plugin for slideshows and isotope for grid. 
Each item in the gallery has its own slider and its own 
isotope item. The Swiper gallery pops up in a fancybox 
and works only on resize.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fancybox.js'></script>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>
    <script src='js/swiper.min.js'></script>
    <script>

        var sliders = [];
        $('.swiper-container').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).addClass('s' + index);
            var slider = new Swiper('.s' + index, {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                paginationClickable: true,
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                spaceBetween: 0,
                speed: 1000,
                autoplay: 4000,
                loop: true,
                paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
                return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                }
            });
            sliders.push(slider);
            slider.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
                console.log('slide change start 2');
                $('.overlay1').hide().delay(700).fadeIn(1400);
                $('.overlay2').hide().delay(700).fadeIn(1400);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                maxWidth: 1170,
                maxHeight: 682,
                fitToView : false,
                autoSize : false,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                closeClick: false,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                closeEffect: 'fade'
            });
            $('.delete').click(
                function () {
                $('input:text').val('').trigger('keyup');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $('#navbar > ul > li').hover(function () {
           $(this).css("background-color", "#f3f3f3");
        }, function () {
           $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        });
       $('.delete').click(
           function () {
           $('input:text').val('').trigger('keyup');
       });
    </script>
    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
```

Comment: can you bring the example to run? https://plnkr.co/edit/sM3XiDIBawhNH7XQZjTL?p=preview ... i miss some html

Comment: For me, the case was Swiper 3.x.x, after updating to Swiper 4.x x events started to work :) Note that there are some other little changes like `pagination` argument which is now an `object` , e.g. `paginationClickable` argument now becoms a subargument of `pagination`:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `pagination{ clickable: true, el: '.swiper-pagination'  }`

Answer (score 1):

you should move the creation of the silder also into the document ready event handler. And It would be better wenn you move the 3 script tags in on java script file.

```
$( function() {

      var sliders = [];
        $('.swiper-container').each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).addClass('s' + index);
            var slider = new Swiper('.s' + index, {
                pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
                paginationClickable: true,
                nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
                prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
                spaceBetween: 0,
                speed: 1000,
                autoplay: 4000,
                loop: true,
                paginationBulletRender: function (swiper, index, className) {
                return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
                }
            });
            sliders.push(slider);
            slider.on('slideChangeStart', function () {
                console.log('slide change start 2');
                $('.overlay1').hide().delay(700).fadeIn(1400);
                $('.overlay2').hide().delay(700).fadeIn(1400);
            });
        });
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                maxWidth: 1170,
                maxHeight: 682,
                fitToView : false,
                autoSize : false,
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                closeClick: false,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                closeEffect: 'fade'
            });
            $('.delete').click(
                function () {
                $('input:text').val('').trigger('keyup');
            });
        });

  $('#navbar > ul > li').hover(function () {
           $(this).css("background-color", "#f3f3f3");
        }, function () {
           $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
        });
       $('.delete').click(
           function () {
           $('input:text').val('').trigger('keyup');
       });
```